# Selecting two sets of data individually grouped

Tags: mysql, sql

Using the following query to select data from a table in 15 minute intervals where a point has state=1:

```
SELECT * , ROUND( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( log_date ) / ( 15 *60 ) ) AS period
FROM  `site_node_point_states` 
WHERE state =1
AND site_node_point_id =  "11"
AND log_date
BETWEEN  '2011-09-12 13:00:00'
AND  '2011-09-12 13:00:00'
GROUP BY period
ORDER BY period ASC
```

This query does exactly what I want based on a single `site_node_point_id`, however I would like to be able to add another `site_node_point_id` and have that grouped by `period` individually of the other `site_node_point_id` data.

I am using PHP to make this query, and would like to try and limit it to a single query rather than looping through my current one with a different `site_node_point_id`.

Obviously If I were to change `AND site_node_point_id =  "11"` to `AND site_node_point_id =  "11" OR site_node_point_id =  "14"` it would order data from both `site_node_point_id` 14 and 11.

Is there a solution in SQL to do the `GROUP BY` individually for each set of data based on the `site_node_point_id` that I am selecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY site_node_point_id, period`.  That should group your results first by site_node_point_id, then period.

Comment: This worked for me, I could have sworn I tried this to begin with. But that could have just been down to tiredness. Thanks.

Comment: @N1ck: You could thank by formally [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. That is quite an established (and nice, too) form of thanking here on SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * , ROUND( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( log_date ) / ( 15 *60 ) ) AS period
FROM  `site_node_point_states` 
WHERE state =1
AND site_node_point_id in ("11", "12")
AND log_date
BETWEEN  '2011-09-12 13:00:00'
AND  '2011-09-12 13:00:00'
GROUP BY site_node_point_id, period
ORDER BY site_node_point_id, period ASC
```